# Why does the numbers in the score stack on itself rather than change the integer?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm making a game in my high school computer science class and the score is supposed to increase every time the `a` key is pressed.

```py
from Tkinter import * 
root = Tk()
score = 0
canvas = Canvas(root, height=600, width=600, relief=RAISED, bg='brown')
canvas.grid() 
canvas.grid(row=0, column=1)
img = PhotoImage(file='C:\\Users\\s27538750\\Desktop\\Create_Task\\Bench- 
Press.gif')
img2 = PhotoImage(file='C:\\Users\\s27538750\\Desktop\\Create_Task\\Bench- 
Press-Up.gif')
canvas.create_image(300, 300, image=img)
canvas.create_text(300, 50, text= 'SWOLE PEEP SIMULATOR!', font=0) 
from Tkinter import *


def key(event):
    global score
    canvas.create_image(300, 300, image=img2)
    score += 1
    canvas.create_text(70, 50, text= score)


def callback(event):
    canvas.focus_set()


canvas.bind("a", key)
canvas.bind("<Button-1>", callback)
canvas.pack()


def key(event):
    canvas.create_image(300, 300, image=img)

canvas.bind("b", key)

canvas.create_text(50, 50, text= 'Score: ')  

root.mainloop()
```

While that part of the code works, when the score is updated the previous score
numbers remain on the GUI.

Comment: The score remains because you are creating a new text on the canvas every instance. Rather than that, use a tag or a variable to create a text, and then use _itemconfig_ on it to update your score.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to test it, but the following code should work:

```py
from Tkinter import * 
root = Tk()
score = 0
canvas = Canvas(root, height=600, width=600, relief=RAISED, bg='brown')
canvas.grid() 
canvas.grid(row=0, column=1)
img = PhotoImage(file='C:\\Users\\s27538750\\Desktop\\Create_Task\\Bench- 
Press.gif')
img2 = PhotoImage(file='C:\\Users\\s27538750\\Desktop\\Create_Task\\Bench- 
Press-Up.gif')
canvas.create_image(300, 300, image=img)
canvas.create_text(300, 50, text= 'SWOLE PEEP SIMULATOR!', font=0) 
from Tkinter import *


def key(event):
    global score
    canvas.create_image(300, 300, image=img2)
    score += 1
    canvas.itemconfig(score_text, text = score)


def callback(event):
    canvas.focus_set()


canvas.bind("a", key)
canvas.bind("<Button-1>", callback)
canvas.pack()


def key(event):
    canvas.create_image(300, 300, image=img)

canvas.bind("b", key)

score_text = canvas.create_text(50, 50, text= 'Score: ')  

root.mainloop()
```